# issues with Mod Rewrite with folders inside wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slim

I'm working on a client app and im using the Slim framework.
the root of the site is a wordpress page

and my app stuff is under
http://example.com/yumninja_app_1_0/api/

when you go to the url, it returns a 404, but the 404 is from the wordpress page.

the htaccess file on the root is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

and the htaccess inside my folder (yumninja_app_1_0/api/) is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My question is how to exclude a folder from mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(yumninja_app_1_0|yumninja_app_1_0/.*)$
```

Comment: thanks though, but it still didnt work. for the url [link](http://chasethepaper.com/yumninja_app_1_0/api/getReviews) should return a json array, still goes to the 404 page

Comment: @Tony, I've edited the answer for subfolders. It's the .htaccess in your api folder stopping it now - What are you trying to do with that and can you just remove it?